# How to install libpng 15.so.15 (required by BIOVIA)?

Tags: linux-mint, libraries

I've followed the most steps from BIOVIA installation guideline from the following link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353035302_Method_for_installing_Biovia_Discovery_Studio_Viewer_2021_in_Linux_Mint_201_or_Ubuntu_2004

However, I was stuck in Step.23 to install libpng 15.so.15. I found there were some suggestions about how to download and install the file by (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407746/how-to-install-biovia-discovery-studio-on-lubuntu#new-answer?newreg=5982995cc1bc49599befe8132682908c). It still didn't work for me.

Here are the instructions in Linux Mint terminal: [image]

My Linux Mint system infor:
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description: Linux Mint 21
Release: 21
Codename: vanessa

Can anyone give me some suggestions about how to solve these problems?

Comment: The instructions in [this answer in the question you referred to](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407763/769591) describe building the libpng15.so.15 from source code, which should be the best way to get a library that doesn't match your distributions standard packaged libraries to work with your system. Is the library now at `/usr/local/lib/libpng15.so.15`? What is the output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/libpng15.so.15`? If the `make install` produced errors, you might be missing some `-dev` packages for dependencies. Also, try running `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` if the library is present there.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: you don't.

Your proprietary software depends on a library in a version your system doesn't have – so, you'd have to build that specific version yourself (that's where the answer to the question you linked to fails), and hope you're doing that build exactly the way that was present in previous versions of your Linux distro did. If you did that correctly, the resulting library is binary-compatible with what your BIOVIA Discovery Visualizer needs and still uses the system libraries that you have on your modern distro. If you don't, things might crash at unpredictable points, or, *much* worse for a scientific application, you might just get corrupt output without noticing, invalidating all the sciencing you did.

So. Don't.

Instead, run it in an environment that is known to work. The guide indicates that'd be a CentOS. Easy-peasy.

1. Install podman on your Ubuntu: `sudo apt install podman` (Don't know whether you still have to add your user to the /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid files – I'm not using Ubuntu. If you have to, here's a guide.)
2. Test whether it works: `podman run -it --rm centos:7`. When you get a `root@` shell, things work. `exit`, and you're clean again. If not, need to fix 1. first.
3. Then follow the instructions you have up to (including): `Make executable: "chmod +x install_DSClient.sh"`.
    You now have the extracted installation files in `~/progrs/BIOVIA2021`.
4. We'll create a container that contains all the necessary libraries, and install in that, and run from there.

   4.1. excuse the lengthy command line, but: `podman run --rm -it --name preinstalled -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY  --device /dev/dri  -v /tmp/.X11-unix/X0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 -v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:Z --security-opt label=type:container_runtime_t -v /path/to/progs/BIOVIA2021:/installer:Z centos:7`

   4.2. you're again greeted with a root shell in a container. There, install the packages as specified in the [BIOVIA system requirements document, p. 6](https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS-SERVICES/BIOVIA/PDF/biovia-system-requirements-discovery-studio-2021.pdf) (while simultaneously fixing the typos Dassault system has in its documentation for a many-1000€-software…):
   `yum install -y alsa-lib audit-libs bc bzip2-libs cairo compat-libstdc++-33 compat-libtiff3 e2fsprogs-libs expat fontconfig freetype gd glib2 glibc keyutils-libs krb5-libs libICE libSM libX11 libXau libXdamage libXdmcp libXfixes libXi libXinerama libXmu libXpm libXrender libXt libXtst libXxf86vm libdrm libgcc libjpeg-turbo libnsl libpcap libpng15 libpng15 libselinux libsepol libstdc++ libXext pam tcsh zlib`

   4.3 Now commence installing into the container: `./install_DSClient.sh` and follow the rest of the guide you have. The locations the guide recommends are bonkers, use `/opt/BIOVIA` instead of `~/progs/BIOVIA2021` everywhere. Skip step 23., because `libpng23` is already installed :)

   4.4 When your first run of of the Visualizer is done, open a second terminal (!) and run `podman commit -f docker -m visualizer preinstalled`
5. you can henceforth start the program `podman run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY  --device /dev/dri  -v /tmp/.X11-unix/X0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 -v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:Z --security-opt label=type:container_runtime_t -v /home/data/you/want/to/work/with:data:Z centos:7 /opt/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/bin/DiscoveryStudio2021`.